# find which spring context file loaded bean

Tags: spring

Its a big application and there are multiple bean xml files that get loaded by the spring container.

There is one bean (with the same id) which is being overridden, somehow.

Is there anyway a way to tell spring to log which bean was created from which .xml file?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `ReaderEventListener` and log them. But you need to override `initBeanDefinitionReader` to set your `Listener` on `XmlBeanDefinitionReader` (I think that there is not  other way but may be...).

For example:

```
  public class LogReaderEventListener extends EmptyReaderEventListener {

    private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(LogReaderEventListener.class);

    @Override
    public void componentRegistered(ComponentDefinition componentDefinition) {

        log.info("Registered Component [" + componentDefinition.getName() + "]");
        for (BeanDefinition bd : componentDefinition.getBeanDefinitions()) {
            String name = bd.getBeanClassName();

            if (bd instanceof BeanComponentDefinition) {
                name = ((BeanComponentDefinition) bd).getBeanName();
            }
            log.info("Registered bean definition: [" + name + "]" + 
                    " from " + bd.getResourceDescription());
        }
    }


    public static void main (String[] args) {
        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new LogXmlContext("applicationContext.xml");
        context.close();

    }

}

class LogXmlContext extends ClassPathXmlApplicationContext {

    public LogXmlContext(String configLocation) {
        super(configLocation);
    }

    @Override
    protected void initBeanDefinitionReader(XmlBeanDefinitionReader reader) {
        super.initBeanDefinitionReader(reader);
        reader.setEventListener(new LogReaderEventListener());
    }

}
```