# Find bean definition file name from spring FileSystemXmlApplicationContext

Tags: java, spring, javabeans

I am loading beans with `FileSystemXmlApplicationContext` into context.

There are some additional resource files included:

```
import resource="beandef_1.xml"
import resource="beandef_2.xml"
```

I am looking for possibility to find out the bean definition source file.

Is it posible to determine from which xml file the bean is loaded?

Many Thx

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10624152/find-which-spring-context-file-loaded-bean

Answer (score 6):

try this

```
FileSystemXmlApplicationContext ctx = ...
String res = ctx.getBeanFactory().getBeanDefinition("bean1").getResourceDescription();
```